# Date validation within pariode of time in PHP

Tags: php, date, timestamp

How do I check date strings with timestamp format (exp. `2014-10-02 13:31:53`) is falls within specific period of time in PHP.

Such as:

1. Daily period: Today, tomorrow, yesterday, two days ago, and so on
2. Weekly period: This week, next week, last week, two weeks ago, and so on
3. Monthly period: This month, next month, last month, two months ago, and so on
4. Yearly period: This year, next year, last year, two years ago, and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class (PHP 5.2+) and use the comparison operators. For example, compare if in this month as follows;

```
$start = new DateTime("First day of this month 00:00:00");
$end = new DateTime("Last day of this month 23:59:59");
$datetotest = new DateTime("2014-10-02 13:31:53");

if($datetotest >= $start and $datetotest <= $end) {
// do stuff
}
```

You can even write a function for each of these if you want.

```
function isInThisMonth(DateTime $date) {
     $start = new DateTime("First day of this month 00:00:00");
     $end = new DateTime("Last day of this month 23:59:59");
     return ($date >= $start and $date <= $end);
}

if(isInThisMonth($datetotest)) // do stuff
```

If you take a look at [PHP: DateTime Relative Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) that will give you an idea of the descriptions you can use in order to get a valid `DateTime` for "last year" or whatever.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I know which argument should I use for `DateTime()`?

Comment: Take a look at [DateTime Relative Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php). This lists all the valid relative uses for a relative date, such as "3 years ago". Otherwise, you can use any valid formatted date, like in your example.